# Converting json String into different objects at runtime based on their content

Tags: json, web-services, scala, json4s

I'm invoking a web service that returns JSON.

The service returns either one of the following response.

**case 1:**

JSON:

```
[ {"name":"somevalue1", "key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}, 
        {"name":"somevalue1", "key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"},
        {"name":"somevalue1", "key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"} ]
```

case class:

```
case class ValidResponse(name: String, key1: String, key2: String)
```

**case 2:**

JSON:

```
{"name": "invalid-response"}
```

Case class:

```
case class InvalidResponse(name:String)
```

I'm using json4s to parse the response as follows:

```
val parsedRes = parse(responseJson)
val objs: List[ValidResponse] = j.extract[List[ValidResponse]]
```

This works if the response string is the json in case 1. However, I get a parsedException in case the response string contains the json in case 2. 
How can I handle response of multiple types?

Answer (score 1):

A better way is to use one common class for both types of responses (valid and invalid):

`case class Response(name: String, key1: Option[String], key2: Option[String])`.

Play Framework has a great JSON parser. You can utilize this. Note that your Scala project does not have to be a Play project. You just need to import the library.

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaJson